# Azure alternative for TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was testing with the Batched CI mode of Azure Pipelines. Travis provides the `TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE` variable to get all commits since the last build on this branch. Does Azure provide a similar variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable Build.SourceVersion can get commit ID in Git or the changeset in TFVC. But it can only get the ID of the commit that triggered the build pipeline. I create a command task and use it to output the variable Build.SourceVersion. As you can see, there are 8 commits since the last build on this branch. But the variable just show the lastest commit id.
[image]

So I think you can get them in Associated changes or you can get them through REST API during build.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version=5.0
```

You can refer to here to get more detailed information. https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Get%20Build%20Changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using git on github. The suggested REST API returns the commit hash of the last commit. So still no information about the other commits.
Also I checked the API for changes between 2 builds(This would require the possibility to determine the previous build on this branch), but this returns an empty list. So no progress yet.